# How to prove the size of a set using Lagrange's theorem?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be prime and $d|p-1$. Suppose $R=\{1,2,...,p-1\}$ and $S=\{x^d:x\in R\}$.

I need to prove $|S|=\frac{(p-1)}{d}$. So far I have shown that $|S| \leq \frac{(p-1)}{d}$ by showing if $y\in S$ then $y^{\frac{(p-1)}{d}}\equiv1 \mod p$, and since any element of $S$ has this property then there there are at most $\frac{(p-1)}{d}$ such elements (by Lagrange's theorem).

Now I need to prove it actually meets this upper bound but I am unsure how to proceed. The only hint I have is to consider the set $R_s=\{x \in R : x^d \equiv s \mod p\}$ for each $s \in S$ and use Lagrange's theorem again.

But I don't know how to finish the problem.

Comment: Sasha's answer is good. Now, another approach is as follows. Let $[x]$ denote the congruence class of $x$ modulo $p$ and let $[g]$ be a generator of the multiplicative group of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^*$ Then consider the set $A:=\left\{\left[g^{3k}\right]:k\in\mathbb Z\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;0\leqslant k\leqslant(p-4)/3\right\}.$

Answer (score 1):

1. By Lagrange's theorem one can prove that if $p$ is a prime and $d$ a divisor of $p-1$ then there are $d$ unique solutions modulo $p$ to the equation $x^d-1 \equiv \pmod{p}$ ( for proof see [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026146/how-to-count-the-number-of-solutions-for-this-expression-modulo-a-prime-number) ).
2. Now let these $d$ unique solutions modulo $p$ be $(m_1=1),m_2,...,m_d$. You can also prove easily that if $gcd(a,p)=1$ then $a*1,a*2,a*3,...,a*(p-1)$ is just a permutation of $1,2,3...,(p-1)$.
3. Now let $x^d \equiv b \pmod{p}$ have a solution, let's call it $c$. Then it can be checked that $m_1c,m_2,...,m_dc$ ( includes $c$ also ) are solutions as well and are all different modulo $p$ ( by point $2$ ). So there are $d$ unique solutions to $x^d \equiv b \pmod{p}$ ( if solution exists ). There can't be more as Lagrange theorem ( see here  [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(number_theory)) ) shows there can be atmost $d$ solutions to it. Thus the size of the set becomes $\frac{p-1}{d}$.