# Why if $q^e \mid p-1$ then $x^{q^e} - 1$ has exactly $q^e$ roots?

Tags: number-theory

Consider solutions of $x^{q^e} \equiv 1 \bmod p.$ If $q^e\mid (p−1),$ then $x^{q^e}−1$ has exactly $q^e$ roots $\mod p.$ $p$ is a prime, $q, e$ are another integers.

But why? Well, i know that $x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p.$

Comment: I imagine that $p$ is a prime?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net thanks, yes)

Comment: Are what are $q$ and $e$? Please update your post!

Comment: Check out the following solution I had posted sometime back http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026146/how-to-count-the-number-of-solutions-for-this-expression-modulo-a-prime-number/2026161#2026161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots modulo $p$.

$$x^{p-1}-1=(x^{q^e}-1)\cdot(youknowwhat)$$

has $p-1$ roots by Fermat's little theorem, and the factors in the RHS have at most $q^e$ and $p-1-q^e$, respectively. So they must have the maximum possible number of roots.

Answer (score 1):

The following makes it completely clear why we expect such a result, but requires a little more abstract algebra.

By Fermat's little theorem, $x^{p-1}-1$ splits completely over $\mathbb F_p$, hence so does every divisor of it. Because $x^{p-1}-1$ has no double roots, the same is true for its divisors.

---

More explicitly:
$$x^{p-1}-1=(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-(p-1)).$$

By unique factorisation in $\mathbb F_p[x]$, every monic divisor of $x^{p-1}-1$ is product of some irreducible elements in the prime factorisation of $x^{p-1}-1$ (just as in $\mathbb Z$), hence splits completely and has no double roots.

---

Note: It is important that $p$ is prime: $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$, but mod $8$, $x+3$ is a divisor of it that is not a product of the irreducibles $x-1$ and $x+1$.

Comment: very nice, thanks!